# Drag & drop with .ui files

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qt4

I'm having big troubles with drag & drop. I've created a new Qt Designer Form Class in which I have one QListWidget and one QWidget. Now I want to enable dragging & dropping between these two widgets.

The problem is, where can I add dragEnterEven(...), dragMoveEvent(...) etc. functions? I only have these class.h, class.cpp and class.ui files.

Any help is much appreciated!

-Samuli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, if you haven't read Qt's [Drag and Drop](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/dnd.html) documentation you really want to start there.  What I'm going to tell you is a summary of what's there.  You also should definitely look at the [drag and drop examples](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/examples.html#drag-and-drop) once you've read the description of the process.

Secondly, and I apologize if I'm misreading this, your question makes it sound like you aren't quite familiar with C++.  You want to declare methods in the `.h` file, and define them in the `.cpp` file.  You can use the Designer to do some of that declaration of events, but you will need to define the implementation of those events in the `.cpp`. If that's not clear you will need to go read more about basic C++ first.

If you're ok with those basics, here's a short summary of how drag and drop works:

- Dragging is done by:

  - Creating a `QDrag`.  You want to do this in the event that triggers the drag, which is, in all cases I can think of a mouse-click (`mousePressEvent` or `mouseMoveEvent` -- which one depends on the exact behavior you want to see).
  - Encoding the data you want to be dragged.  You do this using MIME-encoding, a standard way of marking what type of document is being dragged.  (Examples include text, images, and most other media formats).  Assume text for the simple case.

    - Create a `QMimeData`
    - Set data for the appropriate type (e.g. for text use `QMimeData::setText`)\
    - Add the mime data to the drag object with `QDrag::setMimeData`.
    - Call `QDrag::exec` on your drag object.
- Dropping is done by:

  - Enabling the `acceptDrops` property on the given widget using `QWidget::setAcceptDrops(true)`.
  - Define `dropEvent` on your widget to handle the drop.  The data you set in the drag using `setMimeData` is available as a method of the drop event `QDropEvent::mimeData`.  You need to extract the data out of it using the appropriate document type (e.g. `text()`).

Obviously this isn't complete, but drag and drop has enough steps that you really should read about them in detail once and look at some examples.  This summary is meant to give you an idea of what you need to do.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to subclass the `QListWidget` and `QWidget` that you want to be able to drag and drop between, and handle the events in those implementations.  If you do this, you should be able to right-click in designer and promote the widgets in your main .ui file.

If you would rather not subclass, you could look into event filters, and install an event filter on each of those widgets.  The event filter could then handle the events that cause the `dragEnterEvent()` and `dragMoveEvent()` to be called.  This would likely be more confusing to anyone looking at your code later.

I also second [quark's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730944/drag-drop-with-ui-files/1731046#1731046) of perusing the examples.  You can learn a lot by taking a working example and trying to modify it to do something slightly different.